# Hit send / press enter for already written text in chrome address bar with JavaScript

Tags: google-chrome-extension, address-bar

Suppose the user has the following text written in the chrome address bar:
"google this"

I need my chrome extension command to hit the send button or enter for this text so that a search query can be initiated. Then I read in the `onBeforeRequest` listener to add some other parameters to the search and redirect to a new URL.

It appears that it's not possible to read and modify the address bar text directly, which is why I resorted to this indirect way.

My question is: **how do I initiate the search so that user can press my command shortcut to search instead of the 'Enter' button?**

Comment: There's no way. The only workaround is to write a separate utility and invoke it through nativeMessaging.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate utility"?

Comment: See the documentation for nativeMessaging.